# Разница между UI и unit-тестами

Tags: android, android-sdk, юнит-тесты, espresso

Какая разница разница между UI (Espresso, Robotium) и unit-тестами (Robolectric)? Как правильно их использовать при разработке? Когда их нужно запускать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Юнит-тесты должны тестировать внутреннюю структуру программы, работу классов желательно по отдельности. При этом юнит-тесты должны выполняться как можно быстрее и использовать как можно меньше классов в каждом тесте, в идеале только тестируемый класс. При этом желательно абстрагироваться от базы данных, общения по сети и свести к минимуму обращение к файловой системе, все это ради скорости.

Интеграционные тесты и тесты интерфейса могут выполняться дольше. Интеграционные тесты  предназначены для тестирования связей между классами, которые были протестированы юнит-тествми. Для интеграционных тестов можно использовать имеющиеся для юнит-тестов инструменты, а кто-то пишет для них свои инструменты.

Тестирование интерфейса - это тестирование на еще более высоком уровне, когда нажимаются кнопки в интерфейсе и осуществляются другие действия, которые может делать пользователь.

Во всех случаях нужно не забыть протестировать те данные или действия, которые пользователь не должен вводить, чтобы убедиться, например, что программа не упадет, если пользователь введет буквы там, где ожидается число.

Comment: Чем обусловлена борьба за скорость выполнения Unit тестов? Согласен что они должны тестировать какую-то небольшую часть программы(класс, метод), но не вижу смысла гнаться за скоростью их выполнения. В конце концов на устройстве работает приложение, а не тесты.

Comment: Потому что если тесты выполняются долго, то программисту будет лень их запускать часто, а их надо запускать после каждого, даже небольшого, изменения.

Comment: Ну вообще полным прогоном тестов должен заниматься CI сервер, ну или если его нет, то прогонять их когда завершен фикс бага или реализован какой либо функционал. Абстрагироваться от БД, сохранения файла на диск и т.д. то же не желательно, т.к. мало ли была совершена ошибка при подготовке данных к записи. Да и тесты классов работы с БД не занимают много времени.